# Problems with '\0' in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

For some reason, when I execute case 1, I am assigned the time 4pm, so it doesn't find the \0 in the first 3 instances of i, but finds it on the fourth.  I am just a little confused on how the null character works with a 2d array, is it stored by default in every row, does it need to be added?  I am trying to have a 5x20 array with 5 different slots for names.  Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int total=0;
    int opt;
    int time;
    char x[5][20];
    char name[20];

    printf("----MAIN MENU----\n");
    printf("1: Request a lesson\n");
    printf("2: Cancel a lesson\n");
    printf("3: See available lessons\n");
    printf("4: List all names starting with a letter\n"); 
    printf("9: Quit\n");


    for(;;)
    {
        scanf("%d",&opt);
        switch(opt)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("please enter your name\n");
                scanf("%s",name);

                //if schedule is full
                if(total==5)
                {   
                    printf("Sorry, the teacher is too busy, try again tomorrow.\n");
                }


                //opening in schedule
                else
                    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
                        if (x[i][0]=='\0')
                        {
                            strcpy(x[i], name);
                            total++;
                            printf("You have been assigned the time %dpm\n",i+1);
                            break;
                        }

                break;
```

Comment: The arrays are never initialized...

Comment: ..specifically `x` from which you read before it has any valid data.

Comment: what happens if name is greater than 19 characters plus nul terminator `\0`. `NULL` and nul are two completely different beasts.

Comment: You can initialise `x` simply with `char x[5][20] = {{0}};` You only need to initialise the first element and the compiler will ensure the rest will be `0`. (If you initiliase the first array element to `1`, the rest will still be initialised to `0`). Otherwise, local variables are not initiliased unless you do it explicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389220/problems-with-0-in-2d-array/40389395#comment68030148_40389220) is correct, op. You will have undefined behavior if you don't initialize those arrays. I suggest you insert the nul character '\0' on every first position, to make it coherent with the code you had already done. You could do that on your main function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) x[i][0] = '\0';
```